# how to Find the Search Paths\Header Search Paths setting in xcode 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c

all 
i am very to iphone development  and i am doing one tutorial which is related to the XML parser  from the link http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml .i searched everywhere but not got .i have one query if anyone can help me:
i am not able to find this:

1.Find the Search Paths\Header Search Paths setting and add /usr/include/libxml2 to the list. 
2.find the Linking\Other Linker Flags section and add -lxml2 to the list.

thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: The steps in the tutorial are as follows. You just need to read it carefully.

1>>> In XCode, click Project\Edit Project Settings and make sure “All Configurations” are checked.

2>>> Find the Search Paths\Header Search Paths setting and add /usr/include/libxml2 to the list.

3>>> Finally, find the Linking\Other Linker Flags section and add -lxml2 to the list.

Answer (score 2):

1.Open the xcode.

2.Select the Project tab from the menu bar.

3.Select the Edit Project Settings.

4.Select the Build tab and search the **Header Search paths** and set the /usr/include/libxml2.

5.Again search the **Other Linker Flags** and set the -lxml2.

Comment: i don't have that much reputation.can give me your any personal gmail id or skype id .